# Transform with translate Y not aligning vertically in the middle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, transform

I'm trying to get a div to vertically align in the middle of a parent div. I'm using bootstrap for the layout. I have tried to put the following code at the container, row and col level of the HTML but with no luck.

```
  .container { // or .row or .col 
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwLOBY)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. As you will see from the Codepen link above, instead of the desired div being vertically aligned in the middle of the section, it goes UP to go half above and half below the top of the "screen".  I've adjusted the % to 100% instead of -50% which brings it down the screen but that doesn't make sense or follow the code of other Codepens I have seen.

Comment: The problem is you do not have a height set for the parent element, so setting a position relative to its parents height wont work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `position: relative` use `position: absolute`:

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqXLWo?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

```
  .container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
  }
```

Absolute is what you want.

This can be positioned absolutely in its parent container because it has a position set.

**Full solution:**

```
  /* PROBLEM ELEMENT */
  .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```